# Matlab login and download failure when calling WebClient.DownloadFile

Tags: .net, matlab

I have managed to get matlab to login to google Trends to download csv data.  Firstly I used DownloadString and then converted that to a matlab string before using fastawrite to save the csv file.

However even though the string was being downloaded correctly the '\n' lines were losing some of their formatting...which is bizare because if I split the file by '\n' into a cell array the formatting is fine!

So I'm now trying to get the DownloadFile method to work but I keep getting the following error:

No method 'DownloadFile' with matching signature found for class 'System.Net.WebClient'

many thanks,

Here's the function:

```
NET.addAssembly('System.Net');

url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email=email&Passwd=pass&service=trendspro&source=test-test-v1';
durl = System.String(strcat('http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q=', keyWord, '&date=all&geo=all&graph=all_csv&sort=0&scale=1&sa=N'));

if exist('googleWebClient','var')
    client = googleWebClient;
else
    client = System.Net.WebClient;

    response = client.DownloadString(url);
    sid = char(response.ToString);
    sid = regexp(sid, '\n', 'split'); sid = sid(1,1);

    client.Headers.Add('Cookie', char(sid));
    assignin('base','googleWebClient',client);
end

saveFilePath = System.String(strcat('C:\Dropbox\PROJECTS\', keyWord, '.csv'));


data = client.DownloadFile(durl, saveFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of formatting is being lost? Sounds like you might just be getting Unix mode (\n) text and then opening it in a DOS mode (\r\n) editor. A quick `regexprep(sid, '\r?\n', sprintf('\r\n'))` will fix that. Switching to DownloadFile probably won't.

As far as that "no such method" error you're getting, `WebClient.DownloadFile` has a void return type. Looks like Matlab's .NET support considers that part of the signature. Remove the "data = " assignment and it'll go.

```
>> client = System.Net.WebClient;
>> x = client.DownloadFile('http://www.cnn.com', 'C:\temp\blah.html')
No method 'DownloadFile' with matching signature found for class 'System.Net.WebClient'.

>> client.DownloadFile('http://www.cnn.com', 'C:\temp\blah.html')
>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have been banning my head against a wall....I removed the data = and it is downloading the csv file as is.  It seems that when I used the char(data) function to convert from System.String to matlab char and then saving using fastawrite it was damaging the formatting somehow.

Comment: Sorry, the regexprep(sid) formatting is fine, I was using DownloadString as opposed to DownloadFile and there was some formatting errors coming into the csv file for some reason...