# matlab download google trends csv

Tags: .net, matlab

I've been working from original code posted at [Matlab login and download failure when calling WebClient.DownloadFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419444/matlab-login-and-download-failure-when-calling-webclient-downloadfile) to try and download google trends data in a csv directly from matlab.

I also read in Emanuele's post at [login with curl and get session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101151/login-with-curl-and-get-session)  that Google's authentication policy has changed, and now my code looks like this:

```
NET.addAssembly('System.Net'); 

url = strcat(['https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email='     USERNAME '&Passwd=' PASSWORD '&service=trendspro&source=test-test-v1']); 

durl = System.String(strcat('http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q=', keyWord, '&date=all&geo=all&graph=all_csv&sort=0&scale=1&sa=N'))

if exist('googleWebClient','var') 
    client = googleWebClient; 
else 
    client = System.Net.WebClient; 

    response = client.DownloadString(url); 
    sid = char(response.ToString); 
    sid = regexp(sid, '\n', 'split'); 

    client.Headers.Add('Cookies', char(sid(1))); 

    client.Headers.Add('Authorization', strcat(   'GoogleLogin '  ,  char(sid(3))   )   ); 


end 


client.DownloadString(durl)
```

which unforgivingly returns:

```
ans = 

<div id="report">
    <div class="timeBandTitle">An error has been detected</div>
    <div class="timeBandSubTitle">You have reached your quota limit. Please try again later.</div>
  </div>
```

If anybody is able to access google trends csv data from matlab, you are my hero

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not actually gotten to the quota limit, I would suspect that you have not [turned on API access](http://css.dzone.com/articles/getting-quota-error-google-and). (Interpreted as quota limit of 0?!)

It can be found under services.